# Issue with right serial port initialization on Linux

Tags: android, linux, serial-port, tty

I want to attach RFID-reader to my android application, but I'm stuck at the incorrect init code for termios! Reader works (on windows) at 19200 br / 8 data bits /N(o parity) / 1 stop bit.
when running my test console application into WSL enviroment with ubuntu 20.04 inside it's always working well! but when I run it on Ubuntu 20.04 on a real PC (Or android), it returns damaged data on read() but seems that the reader ALWAYS accepts command not damaged, but I'm not sure. I wonder what I'm done wrong? On the same PC sample rewritten to system.io.serialports on netcore 3.1 works great! so it seems only my code issue! (I understand only that windows init serial with some default values and seem didn't proxy all syscalls to winapi )

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define SOH 0x01
#define STX 0x02
#define ETX 0x03
#define EOT 0x04
#define ENQ 0x05
#define ACK 0x06
#define NAK 0x15
#define CAN 0x18


static speed_t getBaudrate(int baudrate)
{
    switch (baudrate) {
    case 0: return B0;
    case 50: return B50;
    case 75: return B75;
    case 110: return B110;
    case 134: return B134;
    case 150: return B150;
    case 200: return B200;
    case 300: return B300;
    case 600: return B600;
    case 1200: return B1200;
    case 1800: return B1800;
    case 2400: return B2400;
    case 4800: return B4800;
    case 9600: return B9600;
    case 19200: return B19200;
    case 38400: return B38400;
    case 57600: return B57600;
    case 115200: return B115200;
    case 230400: return B230400;
    case 460800: return B460800;
    case 500000: return B500000;
    case 576000: return B576000;
    case 921600: return B921600;
    case 1000000: return B1000000;
    case 1152000: return B1152000;
    case 1500000: return B1500000;
    case 2000000: return B2000000;
    case 2500000: return B2500000;
    case 3000000: return B3000000;
    case 3500000: return B3500000;
    case 4000000: return B4000000;
    default: return -1;
    }
}

char bcc(char* buffer, int size)
{
    char result = SOH;
    while (size-->0)result ^= *buffer++;
    return result;
}

void test(int fd)
{
    char cmd_buffer[] = { 0x01, 0x43, 0x31, 0x31, 0x02, 0x03, 0x42 };
    char response_buffer[256];
    char dump_buffer[1025];
    int bytes_available;
    char response;
    char enq = ENQ;

    ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, &bytes_available);
    read(fd, response_buffer, bytes_available);

    memset(response_buffer, 0, sizeof(response_buffer));
    memset(dump_buffer, 0, sizeof(dump_buffer));
    if (fd < 0)
        printf("Bad file descriptor!\n");
    write(fd, cmd_buffer, sizeof(cmd_buffer));
    bytes_available = 0;

    while (!bytes_available)
    {
        ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, &bytes_available);
        usleep(100000);
    }
    read(fd, &response, 1);

    if (response == ACK)
    {
        //printf("OK! ACK was recieved!\n");
        write(fd, &enq, 1);
        bytes_available = 0;
        while (bytes_available<14)
        {
            ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, &bytes_available);
            usleep(100000);
        }
        ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, &bytes_available);
        int read_count = read(fd, response_buffer, bytes_available);
        for (int i = 0; i < read_count; i++)
        {
            sprintf(dump_buffer + strlen(dump_buffer), "%02X ", (0xff & response_buffer[i]));
        }

        printf("%s - BCC: %02X, BCC[-1]: %02X\n", dump_buffer, 0xff&bcc(response_buffer, read_count), 0xff & bcc(response_buffer, read_count-1));
    }
    else
        printf("ACK was not recieved!\n");
}

int configTTY2(int fd, int baudrate)
{
    if (ioctl(fd, TIOCEXCL)) {
        printf("configTTY2 open: error setting TIOCEXCL: errno=%d\n", errno);
        return -1;
    }
    speed_t speed = getBaudrate(baudrate);
    struct termios newtio;
    memset(&newtio, 0, sizeof(newtio));
    printf("configTTY2: getting attributes\n");
    if (tcgetattr(fd, &newtio) == -1) {
        printf("configTTY2: tcgetattr failed: errno=%d\n", errno);
        return -2;
    }

    newtio.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
    newtio.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ECHOK | ECHONL | ISIG | IEXTEN);
    newtio.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
    newtio.c_iflag = IGNBRK;
    newtio.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    newtio.c_cflag |= CS8;
    newtio.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    newtio.c_iflag &= ~(INPCK | ISTRIP | IGNPAR | PARMRK);
    newtio.c_cflag &= ~(PARENB | PARODD);
#ifdef HAVE_TERMIOS_CMSPAR
    newtio.c_cflag &= ~CMSPAR;
#endif
    //newtio.c_iflag |= INPCK;
    newtio.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;
    newtio.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
    newtio.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
    newtio.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    //cfmakeraw(&newtio);

    if (cfsetospeed(&newtio, speed) < 0 ||  cfsetispeed(&newtio, speed) < 0)
    {
        printf("error to set speed!\n");
        return -4;
    }
    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSADRAIN, &newtio) < 0) {
        printf("setproperties: setting attributes failed: errno=%d\n", errno);
        return -5;
    }
    //printf("setting attributes done\n");

    fsync(fd);

    // Get the baudrate and compare with what we set
    tcgetattr(fd, &newtio);
    if (cfgetispeed(&newtio) != speed ||
        cfgetospeed(&newtio) != speed) {
        printf("baudrate mismatch. ispeed ret=%d set=%d; ospeed ret=%d set=%d",
            cfgetispeed(&newtio), speed,
            cfgetospeed(&newtio), speed);
        // For some reason the baudrate was not set to what we had asked.
        return -6;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main( int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("\n%s /dev/ttyS0 for select com1\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }
    int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC );
    if (fd < 0 )
    {
        printf("Cannot open port!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (configTTY2(fd, 19200) < 0)
        return -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        printf("%d: ", i);
        test(fd);
    }
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Dump of communication on WSL with ubuntu:
cycled send on get version command to the reader, and it always return correct response
[SOH] 'c' '1' '1' [STX] [P] [STATUS] V 2 . 0 2 [ETX] [BCC]

```
./wsl_serial_test /dev/ttyS4
configTTY2: getting attributes
0: 01 43 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 00, BCC[-1]: 5A
1: 01 43 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 00, BCC[-1]: 5A
2: 01 43 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 00, BCC[-1]: 5A
3: 01 43 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 00, BCC[-1]: 5A
4: 01 43 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 00, BCC[-1]: 5A
5: 01 43 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 00, BCC[-1]: 5A
6: 01 43 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 00, BCC[-1]: 5A
7: 01 43 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 00, BCC[-1]: 5A
8: 01 43 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 00, BCC[-1]: 5A
9: 01 43 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 00, BCC[-1]: 5A
10: 01 43 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 00, BCC[-1]: 5A
11: 01 43 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 00, BCC[-1]: 5A
12: 01 43 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 00, BCC[-1]: 5A
13: 01 43 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 00, BCC[-1]: 5A
14: 01 43 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 00, BCC[-1]: 5A
15: 01 43 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 00, BCC[-1]: 5A
16: 01 43 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 00, BCC[-1]: 5A
17: 01 43 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 00, BCC[-1]: 5A
18: 01 43 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 00, BCC[-1]: 5A
19: 01 43 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 00, BCC[-1]: 5A
20: 01 43 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 00, BCC[-1]: 5A
21: 01 43 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 00, BCC[-1]: 5A
22: 01 43 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 00, BCC[-1]: 5A
23: 01 43 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 00, BCC[-1]: 5A
24: 01 43 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 00, BCC[-1]: 5A
25: 01 43 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 00, BCC[-1]: 5A
26: 01 43 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 00, BCC[-1]: 5A
27: 01 43 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 00, BCC[-1]: 5A
28: 01 43 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 00, BCC[-1]: 5A
29: 01 43 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 00, BCC[-1]: 5A
```

Dump of communication on PC with ubuntu:

```
 ./wsl_serial_test /dev/ttyS0
configTTY2: getting attributes
0: 01 43 31 39 02 D0 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 88, BCC[-1]: D2
1: 01 43 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 83 5A  - BCC: 80, BCC[-1]: DA
2: 01 43 31 31 02 58 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 08, BCC[-1]: 52
3: 01 43 31 71 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 40, BCC[-1]: 1A
4: 01 43 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 00, BCC[-1]: 5A
5: 01 43 B1 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 80, BCC[-1]: DA
6: 01 53 31 31 82 50 00 56 32 2E 60 32 03 5B  - BCC: C1, BCC[-1]: 9A
7: 01 43 31 99 02 50 00 5E 32 2E 30 32 03 AE  - BCC: 54, BCC[-1]: FA
8: 01 43 31 31 02 A0 00 56 32 2E 30 9A 03 5A  - BCC: 58, BCC[-1]: 02
9: ACK was not recieved!
10: 01 43 31 31 02 B0 00 F6 32 2E 30 32 83 5A  - BCC: C0, BCC[-1]: 9A
11: ACK was not recieved!
12: 01 43 31 31 02 50 02 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 02, BCC[-1]: 58
13: ACK was not recieved!
14: 01 43 31 31 02 B0 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 BA  - BCC: 00, BCC[-1]: BA
15: 01 43 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 43 5A  - BCC: 40, BCC[-1]: 1A
16: 81 43 31 71 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: C0, BCC[-1]: 9A
17: ACK was not recieved!
18: 81 43 31 31 82 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 00, BCC[-1]: 5A
19: ACK was not recieved!
20: 01 43 31 31 82 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 80, BCC[-1]: DA
21: 01 43 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 00, BCC[-1]: 5A
22: 01 43 D9 CC 81 D0 00 56 B2 2E 30 36 03 5A  - BCC: 92, BCC[-1]: C8
23: ACK was not recieved!
24: 81 A3 31 31 02 50 00 56 32 2E 31 9A 03 5A  - BCC: C9, BCC[-1]: 93
25: 01 63 31 35 02 A8 80 AE 32 2E 38 32 03 5A  - BCC: AC, BCC[-1]: F6
26: 01 C3 31 31 02 50 00 56 9A 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 28, BCC[-1]: 72
27: 01 43 31 63 02 50 01 56 32 2E 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 53, BCC[-1]: 09
28: ACK was not recieved!
29: 81 43 31 33 02 50 00 56 32 AE 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 02, BCC[-1]: 58
```

dotnet test on the same ubuntu PC:

```
~/test_net$ dotnet run --port:/dev/ttyS0
Ack was received, send ENQ
Respose:
01-43-31-31-02-50-00-56-32-2E-30-32-03-5A

~/test_net$ dotnet run --port:/dev/ttyS0
Ack was received, send ENQ
Respose:
01-43-31-31-02-50-00-56-32-2E-30-32-03-5A

/test_net$ cat Program.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace core_serial_test
{
    class Program
    {
        static byte ACK = 0x06;
        static byte ENQ = 0x05;
        class Anchor { };
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string portName=null;
            foreach(var arg in args)
            {
                var kv = arg.Split(new char[] { ':' });
                if(kv.Length==2)
                {
                    switch(kv[0])
                    {
                        case "--port":
                            portName = kv[1];
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(portName==null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} --port:[comport name]", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(new Anchor().GetType().Assembly.Location));
                string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
                                foreach(var port in ports) Console.WriteLine(port);
                return;
            }
            SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort(portName, 19200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            serialPort.Open();
            byte[] cmd = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x43, 0x31, 0x31, 0x02, 0x03, 0x42 };
            byte[] response = new byte[200];
            serialPort.Write(cmd, 0, cmd.Length);
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            serialPort.Read(response, 0, 1);
            if (response[0] == ACK)
                serialPort.Write(new byte[] { ENQ }, 0, 1);
            else
                return;
            Console.WriteLine("Ack was received, send ENQ");
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            int size = 0;
            if (serialPort.BytesToRead > 0)
            {
                size = serialPort.Read(response, 0, serialPort.BytesToRead);
            }
            serialPort.Close();
            Array.Resize<byte>(ref response, size);
            Console.WriteLine("Respose: ");
            Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(response, 0, response.Length));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE today i've trying this code sample:

```
int open_tty(char* ttyname, int baudrate)
{
    int USB = open(ttyname, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
    struct termios tty;
    struct termios tty_old;
    memset(&tty, 0, sizeof(tty));
    if (tcgetattr(USB, &tty) != 0) {
        std::cout << "Error " << errno << " from tcgetattr: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    tty_old = tty;
    cfsetospeed(&tty, (speed_t)baudrate);
    cfsetispeed(&tty, (speed_t)baudrate);
    tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;            // Make 8n1
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    tty.c_cflag |= CS8;
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;           // no flow control
    tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;                  // read doesn't block
    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;                  
    tty.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL;     // turn on READ & ignore ctrl lines
    cfmakeraw(&tty);
    tcflush(USB, TCIFLUSH);
    tcflush(USB, TCOFLUSH);
    if (tcsetattr(USB, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) {
        std::cout << "Error " << errno << " from tcsetattr" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    return USB;
} 

char bcc(char* buffer, int size)
{
    char result = SOH;
    while (size-- > 0)result ^= *buffer++;
    return result;
}

void test(int fd)
{
    char cmd_buffer[] = { 0x01, 0x43, 0x31, 0x31, 0x02, 0x03, 0x42 };
    char response_buffer[256];
    char dump_buffer[1025];
    char response;
    char enq = ENQ;

    memset(response_buffer, 0, sizeof(response_buffer));
    memset(dump_buffer, 0, sizeof(dump_buffer));
    if (fd < 0)
        printf("Bad file descriptor!\n");
    write(fd, cmd_buffer, sizeof(cmd_buffer));
    usleep(50000);
    while(1!=read(fd, &response, 1))
        usleep(10000);
    if (response == ACK)
    {
        write(fd, &enq, 1);
        usleep(2000);
        int read_count = 0;
        while (read_count < 14)
        {
            read_count+=read(fd, response_buffer + read_count, 1);
            usleep(1000);
        }
        if (read_count > 7)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < read_count; i++)
            {
                sprintf(dump_buffer + strlen(dump_buffer), "%02X ", (0xff & response_buffer[i]));
            }

            printf("%s - BCC: %02X, BCC[-1]: %02X\n", dump_buffer, 0xff & bcc(response_buffer, read_count), 0xff & bcc(response_buffer, read_count - 1));
        }
        else
        {
            tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);  
            tcflush(fd, TCOFLUSH);  
            printf("read result is %d\n", read_count);
        }
    }
    else
    {
            printf("ACK was not recieved [%02X] !\n", 0xff & response);
            tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);  
            tcflush(fd, TCOFLUSH);  
    }
}
```

changes inside of main()

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
if (argc == 2 && argv[1][0] == '4')
        {
            int fd = open_tty("/dev/ttyUSB0", B1200);
            int n = 0,
                spot = 0;
            char buf = '\0';

            /* Whole response*/
            char response[1024];
            memset(response, 0, sizeof response);
            usleep(10000);
            do {
                n = read(fd, &buf, 1);
                if (n)
                {
                    sprintf(&response[spot], "%c", buf);
                    printf("%c - %02X\n", buf, buf & 0xff);
                    spot += n;
                }
            } while (buf != '\r' && n > 0);

            if (n < 0) {
                std::cout << "Error reading: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
            }
            else if (n == 0) {
                std::cout << "Read nothing!" << std::endl;
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "Response: " << response << std::endl;
            }
            close(fd);
        }
        else
        if (argc == 2 && argv[1][0] == '5')
        {
            int fd = open_tty("/dev/ttyS0", B19200);
            test(fd);
            close(fd);
        }

}
```

For serial initialization, result read text from another device works fine, reader response still didn't looks like a normal one!

read text from weight terminal emulator ( that was on /dev/ttyUSB0 )

```
./wsl_serial_test 4
P - 50
+ - 2B
  - 20
1 - 31
2 - 32
1 - 31
0 - 30
0 - 30
 - 0D
Response: P+ 12100
./wsl_serial_test 4
P - 50
+ - 2B
  - 20
1 - 31
2 - 32
1 - 31
0 - 30
0 - 30
 - 0D
Response: P+ 12100
./wsl_serial_test 4
P - 50
+ - 2B
  - 20
1 - 31
2 - 32
1 - 31
0 - 30
0 - 30
 - 0D
Response: P+ 12100

./wsl_serial_test 5
01 43 D9 CC 81 50 00 56 32 2E B0 32 03 5A  - BCC: 16, BCC[-1]: 4C
./wsl_serial_test 5
01 43 31 31 82 50 00 56 32 2E 30 32 23 5A  - BCC: A0, BCC[-1]: FA
./wsl_serial_test 5
01 43 31 35 02 50 00 D6 32 AE 30 32 03 5A  - BCC: 04, BCC[-1]: 5E
```

Conclusion read text from relatively slow (9600 bps) device work normal, but on reader issue still exists.

Comment: A quick review indicates two issues with your code.  (1) Numerous syscalls do not have the return code checked for errors.  (2) Your program uses a dangerous setting of VMIN=0 and VTIME=0.  When combined with issue #1, your program could process garbage from the receive buffer, e.g. `response`.  Instead try VMIN=1.

Comment: @sawdust i've tried many samples of code past few days(include few vmin variants), but without any luck. when i'm attach microcontroller(to usb) that generate text string  and write to serial and trying to read it (with the same code) except speed and serial's file name it works grate! seems that i've issue only when reads data response in non text format/range?

Comment: And i'm wondering why same code works fine inside WSL.

Comment: there is two serial ports on the device when i trying to open /dev/ttyS0 write one byte and read in from /dev/ttyS1 ( ports connected to eachother) all works fine, send 100 bytes, receive 100 bytes without any distortions, my brain are gonna blow from that.

Comment: Do not expand your question with multiple problems and/or code variations, otherwise your post will be closed.  If you're not going to properly check the return code from syscalls as I already mentioned, then do not expect your program to behave correctly.   *"i've tried many samples of code... "* -- And I've posted on the failings of a lot of code.  Look at my old answers for examples of POSIX-compliant code for raw and cooked mode.

Comment: Are you kidding? I'm difenitly not linux developer. I've only one problem, and cause it's hard to repeat without reader i've to post a lot of data test and code variants that i've done to test already, in a hope that some skilled in that part can point me what make the trouble. i still didnt understand why the SAME BINARY file work well on WSL and didn't on real OS with the same reader and OS (both ubuntu 20.04). And as i think it's totally not about how i'm calling read() and write(), or checking syscall results, it's only about how file descriptor open and how termios init.

Comment: Just for a test to 'POSIX compilance', rewrite my test with libserialport (with sp_blocking_read / sp_blocking_write), and still no success, i've get right response, well if at least one of the ten responses is read correctly. The same library reads text data from /dev/ttyUSB0 correctly.